# how to create list view.In list view contained two list view,check box and data retrieve from sqlite database?

Tags: android

I am new android developer.how to create list view.In list view contained two text view,one check box and data retrieve from sqlite database for show text view value.when i pressed button send sms for select list view contained.and one check box for t view select all option.please help me?

### Heading ##StudentListDatabaseHelper.class

```
package com.example.dao;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.dto.DriverSelectedRouteArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class StudentListDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    SQLiteDatabase db;

//  ParseDriverSelectedRouteId parseDriverSelectedRouteId = new ParseDriverSelectedRouteId();

    //database version
    private final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    //table name
    private final static String TABLE_NAME = "studentlist";

    //table column
    private final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    private final String ROUTE_ID  = "route_id";
    private final String KEY_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
    private final String KEY_MIDDLE_NAME = "middle_name";
    private final String KEY_LAST_NAME = "last_name";
    private final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

    DriverSelectedRouteArrayList driverSelectedRouteArrayList = new DriverSelectedRouteArrayList();

//  list object create for student list
    List<DriverSelectedRouteArrayList> studentList = new ArrayList<DriverSelectedRouteArrayList>();
    //constructor
    public StudentListDatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {

        super(context, "sbtsystem.db", null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        //SQLiteDatabase simpleDb = this.

        db = context.openOrCreateDatabase("sbtsystem.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);

//      Log.d("constructor for database handler====>", "database handler");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {

        //Log.d("on create method==========================>>>>>", "sql helper class");
        String  CREATE_STUDENT_LIST_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME +"("+
                                            KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+   
                                            ROUTE_ID+" INTEGER,"+
                                            KEY_FIRST_NAME+" TEXT,"+ 
                                            KEY_MIDDLE_NAME+" TEXT,"+ 
                                            KEY_LAST_NAME+ " TEXT,"+ KEY_PH_NO +" TEXT"+")";
                    db.execSQL(CREATE_STUDENT_LIST_TABLE);  
                    //Log.d("on create database helper calss", "database helper class on create");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        Log.d("on upgrade method in sqlite database helper class=====>", "before on crete method call in onUpgrade method");
         this.onCreate(db);

    }

    public void insertRecord(DriverSelectedRouteArrayList driverSelectedRouteArrayList) throws JSONException
    {
        this.onUpgrade(db, 0, 2);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //get list size from driverSelectedRouteArraylist
        int listSize = driverSelectedRouteArrayList.getStudentArrayList().size();

//      Log.d("list size in database helper class", listSize+"");
        String respose = driverSelectedRouteArrayList.getStudentArrayList().toString();


        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(respose);

            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
            {

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                String routeId = jsonObject.get("route_id").toString();
                values.put(ROUTE_ID, routeId);

                String firstName = jsonObject.get("first_name").toString();
                values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, firstName);

                String middle_name = jsonObject.get("middle_name").toString();
                values.put(KEY_MIDDLE_NAME, middle_name);

                String last_name = jsonObject.get("last_name").toString();
                values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME,last_name);

                String phone_number = jsonObject.get("phone_number").toString();
                values.put(KEY_PH_NO, phone_number);

                try{
                        //onUpgrade(db, 1, 2);
//                      Log.d("end insertRecord loop route id", values.getAsString("route_id")+"end insert record loop route id");
                        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                        selectRecord();

//                      Log.d("insert record:: :: :: :: ::", driverSelectedRouteArrayList.getFirst_name());
                        //db.close();
                        //Log.d("insert query", query+"");

                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                        Log.d("inser======0----->", TABLE_NAME+"");
                        //  db.close();
            }
        }
    public <T> List<DriverSelectedRouteArrayList> selectRecord() throws JSONException
    {
        ArrayList<T> studentArrayList = new ArrayList<T>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
//      Log.d("select query=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=> ", selectQuery);
        //db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor curser = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        //Log.d("select all student list=====>", );
        if(curser.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{ 
                    //json object create for stored data
                    JSONObject jsonObjectForStudenntList = new JSONObject();

                    /*  int _id = (curser.getInt(curser.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
                      jsonObjectForStudenntList.put("_id", _id);*/

                    int _id = driverSelectedRouteArrayList.set_id(curser.getInt(curser.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
                    jsonObjectForStudenntList.put("_id", _id);
                    Log.d("sqlite database values_id",""+_id);

                    //Log.d("values from database handler class _id:::::::::-->", (curser.getInt(curser.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)))+"=====values");
                    String firstName = driverSelectedRouteArrayList.setFirst_name(curser.getString(curser.getColumnIndex(KEY_FIRST_NAME)));
                    jsonObjectForStudenntList.put("firstName", firstName);

                Log.d("first Name=======>>>>>", firstName+"first Name");

                    String middleName = driverSelectedRouteArrayList.setMiddle_name(curser.getString(curser.getColumnIndex(KEY_MIDDLE_NAME)));
                    jsonObjectForStudenntList.put("middleName", middleName);

                    String lastName = driverSelectedRouteArrayList.setLast_name(curser.getString(curser.getColumnIndex(KEY_LAST_NAME)));
                    jsonObjectForStudenntList.put("lastName", lastName);

                    String phoneNumber = driverSelectedRouteArrayList.setPhone_number(curser.getString(curser.getColumnIndex(KEY_PH_NO)));
                    jsonObjectForStudenntList.put("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);


                    studentList.add(driverSelectedRouteArrayList);

                    studentArrayList.add((T) jsonObjectForStudenntList.toString());

                }while(curser.moveToNext());

            driverSelectedRouteArrayList.setDriverSelectedRouteArrayList((List<DriverSelectedRouteArrayList>) studentArrayList);

            //driverSelectedRouteArrayList.setStudentListInSqliteDatabse((ArrayList<String>) studentList);

        //Log.d("all select values from sqlite database******",""+studentArrayList);
        }
        Log.d("driver list==>","nnnnnnnnnnnnn\n"+""+driverSelectedRouteArrayList.getDriverSelectedRouteArrayList());
        return studentList;
    }
}
```

### Heading ##DriverSelectedRouteArrayList

```
package com.example.dto;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DriverSelectedRouteArrayList 
{
//  ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> studentArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

//  create list view object 
    public List<DriverSelectedRouteArrayList> driverSelectedRouteArrayList;

    public int _id;
    public String first_name;
    public String middle_name;
    public String last_name;
    public String route_id;
    public String phone_number;
    boolean Box;
    public DriverSelectedRouteArrayList()
    {
        first_name = null;
        middle_name = null;
        last_name = null;
        route_id = null;
        phone_number = null;

    }
    public int get_id() 
    {
        return _id;
    }

    public int set_id(int _id) 
    {
        return this._id = _id;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getStudentArrayList() 
    {
        return studentArrayList;
    }
    public void setStudentArrayList(ArrayList<String> studentArrayList) 
    {
        this.studentArrayList = studentArrayList;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public String setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        return this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getMiddle_name()
    {
        return middle_name;
    }
    public String setMiddle_name(String middle_name) 
    {
        return this.middle_name = middle_name;
    }
    public String getLast_name() 
    {
        return last_name;
    }
    public String setLast_name(String last_name) 
    {
        return this.last_name = last_name;
    }
    public String getRoute_id()
    {
        return route_id;
    }
    public String setRoute_id(String routeId)
    {
        return this.route_id = routeId;
    }
    public String getPhone_number() 
    {
        return phone_number;
    }
    public String setPhone_number(String phone_number) 
    {
        return this.phone_number = phone_number;
    }

    public List<DriverSelectedRouteArrayList> getDriverSelectedRouteArrayList() 
    {
        return driverSelectedRouteArrayList;
    }
    public void setDriverSelectedRouteArrayList(
            List<DriverSelectedRouteArrayList> driverSelectedRouteArrayList) 
    {
        this.driverSelectedRouteArrayList = driverSelectedRouteArrayList;
    }
}
```

### Heading ##StudentCheckBoxAndListShow

```
package com.example.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;


import com.example.dao.StudentListDatabaseHelper;
import com.example.dto.DriverSelectedRouteArrayList;
import com.example.extra.CustomAdapter;
import com.example.extra.StudentListView;
import com.example.input.DriverSelectedRouteinput;
import com.example.url.UrlAccess;
import com.example.webservcie.ParseDriverSelectedRouteId;
import com.google.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventAdapter;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StudentCheckBoxAndListShow extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
{
    //private String SERVICE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/SBTsystem/service/viewAllStudentlist";
    UrlAccess urlAccess = new UrlAccess();
    String urlAccessStringVariable = urlAccess.SERVICE_URL;
    String SERVICE_URL = urlAccessStringVariable+"/viewAllStudentlist";

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    HttpPost httpPost;
    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    HttpClient httpclient ;
    StatusLine statusLine;
    TextView srNumberTextView;


    //regarding list view object
    ListView listView;
//  List<DriverSelectedRouteArrayList> studentList;



//  ListView listView;
    DriverSelectedRouteArrayList driverSelectedRouteArrayList = new DriverSelectedRouteArrayList();
    ParseDriverSelectedRouteId parseDriverSelectedRouteId = new ParseDriverSelectedRouteId();

    StudentListView studentlistView = new StudentListView();

    //customer adapter class
//  CustomAdapter customAdapter;
    StudentListDatabaseHelper studentListDatabaseHelper;

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.student_list_view_show);
        studentListDatabaseHelper = new StudentListDatabaseHelper(this);

        srNumberTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.srNumberTextView);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.studentlistView);

        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        Log.d("student check box class", "oncreate method");

        Log.d("list view ----StudentCheckBoxAndListShow--->","on create method");

//      call async task class       
        new StudentListShowAsyncTask().execute();


    }

    private void populateListView(StudentListDatabaseHelper studentListDatabaseHelper,ListView listView,TextView srNumberTextView) throws JSONException 
    {

        //studentList = studentListDatabaseHelper.selectRecord();






/*//        call values from DriverSelectedRouteArrayList class
        List<DriverSelectedRouteArrayList> data = studentListDatabaseHelper.selectRecord();      
        List<DriverSelectedRouteArrayList> allStudentList = driverSelectedRouteArrayList.getDriverSelectedRouteArrayList();
        Log.d("all student list", ""+allStudentList);

        if(data.size() == 0)
        {
            String meassage = "student list empty";
            Toast.makeText(StudentCheckBoxAndListShow.this, "student list empty...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {


//          Log.d("list view data...", ""+allStudentList);
            driverSelectedRouteArrayList = data.get(0);

            int srNumber = driverSelectedRouteArrayList.get_id();
            Log.d("serial number value", srNumber+"");

            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(StudentCheckBoxAndListShow.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,srNumber);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            srNumberTextView.setText(srNumber);
        }*/ 
    }

    private class StudentListShowAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
    {
        //this.getIntent().getExtras();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(StudentCheckBoxAndListShow.this,""
                                ,"Loading. Please wait...", true);
            progressDialog.show();

            Log.d("on pre execute method=====>", "on preexcute");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            String routeIdFromDriverSelected = extras.getString("routeId");

            try {
                httpPost = new HttpPost(SERVICE_URL);

                DriverSelectedRouteinput driverSelectedRouteinput = new DriverSelectedRouteinput();
                String jsonRequest = driverSelectedRouteinput.createjsonRequestForDriverSelectedRoute(routeIdFromDriverSelected);

                StringEntity stringEntety;
                stringEntety = new StringEntity(jsonRequest);

                stringEntety.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
                stringEntety.setContentType("application/json");

                httpPost.setEntity(stringEntety);

                httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();

                int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

                if(statusCode == 200)
                    {
                        Log.d("status code", statusCode+"");
                        driverSelectedRouteArrayList = parseDriverSelectedRouteId.parseResponseForRouteIdResult(httpResponse);

                        /*int arrayListSize = parseDriverSelectedRouteId.studentList.size();
                        for(int i =0; i<arrayListSize; i++)
                        {
                        Log.d("response first name=-=-==-===-=-=-=-=>"+i, driverSelectedRouteArrayList.getFirst_name()+"");
                        }*/
                        //String routeId = driverSelectedRouteArrayList.getRoute_id();
                        //Log.d("route id------>", routeId);

                        StudentListDatabaseHelper studentListDatabaseHelper1 = new StudentListDatabaseHelper(getBaseContext());
                        //studentListDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                        studentListDatabaseHelper1.insertRecord( driverSelectedRouteArrayList);

                        //int _id = driverSelectedRouteArrayList.get_id();
                        /*String _idString = ""+_id;
                        Log.d("id get from the sqlite database-==-=-=-=>",_idString);*/
                        Log.d("database created", "sqlite database created");
                    }
                //Log.d("status code", statusCode+"");
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
                    populateListView(studentListDatabaseHelper,listView,srNumberTextView);
                } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: did not show list view.how to show list view please tell me.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code,

```
public class Classes extends Activity{

ImageView imageViewNewClass, imageViewDelete;
static ListView mListView;
String[] stg1;
static List<String[]> names2 = null;
private static List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
DataManipulatorClass dataManipulator;

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSpinner;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.classes);

    imageViewNewClass = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.newclass);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.displaydata);

 imageViewNewClass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Classes.this, Class_Create.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

 mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                int position, long id) {

            SparseBooleanArray sp = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
            StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < sp.size(); i++) {
                if (sp.valueAt(i) == true) {
                    String s = ((TextView) mListView.getChildAt(i))
                            .getText().toString();
                    str = str.append(" " + s);
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(Classes.this,
                    "Selected items are " + str.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    dataManipulator = new DataManipulatorClass(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    names2 = dataManipulator.selectAll();
    stg1 = new String[names2.size()];
    int x = 0;
    String stg;

    for (String[] name : names2) {
        stg = "Class Name : " + name[1];
        stg1[x] = stg;
        x++;
    }
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_list_item,
            stg1);
    mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    mListView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.assignmentheader);
    mListView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mListView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(0x99000000));
    mListView.setDividerHeight(1);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (dataManipulator != null)
        dataManipulator.close();
}
}
```

**DataManipulatorClass**

```
public class DataManipulatorClass {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabaseclass.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
static final String TABLE_NAME = "newtableclass";
private static Context context;
static SQLiteDatabase db;
OpenHelper openHelper = null;

private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;

private static final String INSERT = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME
        + "(classname) values (?)";


public DataManipulatorClass(Context context) {
    DataManipulatorClass.context = context;
    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(DataManipulatorClass.context);
    DataManipulatorClass.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    this.insertStmt = DataManipulatorClass.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
}

public long insert(String classname) {
    this.insertStmt.bindString(1, classname);
    return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
}

public void close() {
    if (openHelper != null) {
        openHelper.close();
    }
}

public void deleteAll() {
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
}

public List<String[]> selectAll() {
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,
            new String[] { "id", "classname" }, null, null, null, null,
            "classname asc");
    int x = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String[] b1 = new String[] { cursor.getString(0),
                    cursor.getString(1) };
            list.add(b1);
            x = x + 1;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}

public boolean delete(long rowId) {
    /** this method deletes by id, the first column in your database */
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

public int update(String updateClass) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("classname", Code.className);
    return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, KEY_ROWID + "=" + updateClass,
            null);
}

private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    OpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
                + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, classname TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
}
```

and call this below code inside your submit button click event.

```
this.dataManipulatorClass = new DataManipulatorClass(this);
this.dataManipulatorClass.insert(Code.className);
this.dataManipulatorClass.close();
```

Comment: can you tell me program i didn't understood this information?

Comment: In both the example they have given all code, just modify as per your requirement, what else you want???

Comment: i am not getting how to set sqlite values to text view.

Comment: @Nitin, I have updated my answer, with everything you want, just implement this.

Comment: i have follow above steps please see and tell me whats problem in my code